# Yii2 - Save current database field value in php variable

Tags: php, database, variables, save, yii2

1. I'm making an online store in Yii2.
2. I have a mysql table called products for displaying products in a
   view. This table belongs to ProductsController and Products model. The view uses a ListView and $dataProvider to show a product picture and some relative text and int values, such as name, price, etc. ... It also as in every record displayed a button to purchase.
3. When i click the purchase button it then goes to another controller called EncomendasController and another view which as another table called Encomendas and it's form fields where the client input it's personal data (name, address, etc. ...).
4. What i need to do is: when the client clicks in ProductsController view the button to purchase an item from the listView only that item field name must be stored, perhaps in a variable, and in the new view that is related to EncomendasController the product chosen name will display above the fields that gather the client personal data to finalize the selling process.

**Any ideas?**

**EDIT - detailView with purchase button**

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'options' => ['class' => 'detail1-galeria-view2'],
    'attributes' => [
        // cria um array com a fotografia, em que carrega a path no campo fieldName da bd
        [
            'attribute'=>'',
            //'value'=>$model->foto,
            'value'=>Html::a(Html::img(Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->getBaseUrl() . "/" .$model->foto, ['width'=>'192', 'height' => "256"]), $model->foto),
            'format' => 'raw',
        ],
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'value'=>$model->nome,
        ],
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'value'=>$model->categoria,
        ],
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'value'=>$model->descricao,
        ],
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'value'=>$model->valor.' '.'€',
        ],
        // info
        [
        'attribute'=>'',
        'format' => 'raw',
        'value'=> Html::a(Yii::t('app','PURCHASE'), Url::toRoute(['encomendas/create'])),
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

Comment: Pass `id` of `Products` model in GET or store as hidden input if you'r using post and submit.

Comment: Ok. I read about the procedure and SESSION or GET seem easy to deal. But how to store in the var only the product in that i pressed the purchase button. It may be difficult since all products are being displayed at once by a ListView widget and it's $dataProvider. How can i tell the framework to store that particular product id or name?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that i understand right what you are trying to achieve but you can transfer the product ID to the next controller, which is `EncomendasController`, as GET parameter and then in that controller load all information related to this product by id from the database. For that you need to change url that is generated to each product by adding something like `'&id='.$dataProvider->id` to the end of it.

Comment: But when i press in the view related to ProductsController the purchase button it renders the view from encomendasController with this URL: http://localhost:8888/beladona/web/index.php?r=encomendas%2Fcreate

Comment: In the above Url it can't differentiate what product i want to pass to the new Controller.

Comment: Show us code of your purchase button. And as Aleks said, just add id to your link, and you will have you product id in controller in GET variable.

Comment: Edit is made. Now is showing the code for the hyperlink.